# $(event.target.id).attr("class") returns undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to get ahold of any element in a given set by the class name for the set.

I have one (working) function which appends new elements to the set as they are uploaded (ignore the first bit, the append is at the end):

```
function sortMaps(returnString) {
    returnArray = returnString.split(",");
    imageCount = parseInt(returnArray[0]);
    for (i = 0; i < imageCount; ++i) {
        MapObject = {
            id: returnArray[i+1],
            url: returnArray[i+imageCount+1],
            name: returnArray[i+(imageCount*2)+1],
            coordString: returnArray[i+(imageCount*3)+1],
            width: returnArray[i+(imageCount*4)+1],
            height: returnArray[i+(imageCount*5)+1]
        };

        mapArray[i] = MapObject;
        $("#mapList").append("<li id=\"" + i + "dropdownMap\" class=\"dropdownMap\">" + mapArray[i].name + "</li>");
    }
}
```

And another function which, just as a tester, prints out the id and class of whichever element I click:

```
$(document).click(function (event) {
    console.log(event.target.id);
    console.log($(event.target.id).attr("class"));
});
```

The HTML to which I'm appending things looks like this:

```
<div id="mapperMenu">
    <div class="mapmakerDropdown">
        <button>Maps</button>
        <div class="mapmakerDropdownOptions">
            <ul id="mapList">APPENDED ELEMENTS APPEAR HERE</ul>
      </div>
    </div>
    <form action="returnMapmaker.php" method="post">
        <input type="submit" class="button" value="Save">
    <form>
</div>
```

When I click on one of the appended list elements, the ID appears and is correct, but the class is undefined (although it does appear in the HTML in my Firefox inspector). So here I am because I'm not really sure why this could be happening.

Any help is appreciated! Let me know if you need more info :)

Comment: Use '$(event.target).attr("class")'. And if you really want to use the id, use '$('#'+event.target.id).attr("class")'

Comment: @Reeno `this` is the `document`!

Comment: Yeah, you're right, I changed it.

Comment: Thanks @Reeno! ^^

Comment: @Reeno I added the first part of your comment to my answer as it is a better way to do it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ID selectors start with a `#`.

```
console.log($( '#' + event.target.id ).attr("class"));
//             ^^^
```

Or as mentioned in a comment above, just call jQuery on the element `e.target` directly:

```
console.log($( event.target ).attr("class"));
```